# Form password field is plain text after using jQuery serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login form includes password field. I show this login form in modal way and I would like to handle the form submit response is a special way(actually update the login bar to a account menu), so i prevent the default form submit by

```
$("#myformid").submit(function(event){
   var form = $(this);
   console.log(form.serialize());
   event.preventDefault();
   jQuery.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:5782/login",
      success: function (data) {
        login_form_modal.style.display = 'none';
      },
      data: {
        form: form.serialize(),
      },
      type:"POST",
      async: false,
   });
})
```

I noticed that in the browser debug console, the password is plain text. My question is, is it safe to submit a serialized form using ajax?

'csrf_token=IjI4ODJZjJmMWI5MGU1ZMjM1Y2Y0M2QxNzY3ZGUwZmI5MDki.YcCuVA.3D_79wx6Lp2-hbZWRT04z_eGhbc&username=myusername&password=MyPlainTextPassword'

Thanks,

Comment: `async: false` locks up the entire JS process while the network request is made until the response comes back and is processed. It is deprecated for good reason. Don't do that.

Comment: It is totally normal to be able to see data it in the Dev Tools, basically you are *spying on your own input*. Nothing is encrypted inside a browser, which includes data in a `<form>` and in the Dev Tools. What is unsafe however is that you are using **`http:`** for the AJAX `url:` parameter. It will become safe if sent through **`https:`**.

Comment: Thanks @PeterB, what you said totally makes sense. It's just a serialization. Security things need to be handled by HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the password from the client to the server.

Both the client and the server need to know what it is — the client because it produces it and the server because it has to pass it through the *right* hash algorithm and compare it to whatever is in the database.

What you don't want is for the password to be intercepted **in transit**. The way to do that is to use HTTPS and not plain HTTP. (This obviously doesn't matter when you are working with `localhost` URLs and the data is development data and not production data, but needs to be dealt with for your production deployment).